# Label formatting in Doughnut Chart [Live Charts]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

Is there any way of formtting values/labels in doughnut chart of LiveCharts Extension from Visual Studio for C#/Winforms?
I have this that with a timer updates the chart with the occupancy rate from a database sql. But the value shown is something like: 53.3333335 (too much precision). How can I tweak this?

```
    var request = new RestRequest("api/parks/" + parkId + "/occupancy");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    // execute the request
    response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    java = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Object> occupancy = java.Deserialize<List<Object>>(content);
    string[] partsDate = occupancy[2].ToString().Split(new[] { 'T' }, 
    2);
    DateTime dateNew = DateTime.Parse(partsDate[0] + " " + 
        partsDate[1]);

    float result = float.Parse(occupancy[1].ToString());
    //float oldResult = result;
    result.ToString("0.00");
    pieChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new PieSeries
            {
                Title = "Occupancy",
                Values = new ChartValues<float> {result},
                PushOut = 15,
                DataLabels = true,
        },
    };
```

Here's the preview:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
result.ToString("0.00");
```

to

```
string result = float.Parse(result.ToString("0.00"),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result.ToString("0.00");
```

Should be replaced with

```
result = (float) Math.Round((double)result,2);
```

As you want to round your float on 2 decimals.